# Add media button has stopped working as of 4.5 on the front end

Tags: jquery, wordpress

As of Wordpress 4.5 I have noticed my media button on the front end has stopped working.

Do you know what is the work around for opening the media window on the front end with this new jquery 12.0 library, it seems as though the var frame is not getting picked up on click. And no errors appear either which really complicates the issue. Just reaching out to see if other devs have had the same problem.

I'm banking off this thread too for further clarification... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224139/add-media-has-stopped-working-in-the-front-end-since-4-5-update

Comment: See console for the error.

Comment: No errors appear in the console is what really complicated things.

Comment: With, 4.5.X. wordpress has a new version of jquery. This causes many problems. Please check your media button with firebug (or similar) for errors

Comment: Nothing is showing in the console and no errors are happening, and the funny thing is... some themes I choose from searching wordpress themes in the admin will work just fine and some do not. Yet they are all using the latest version of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

try this Functions

```
 function pre_4_5_jquery () {
// Load jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"), false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('init', 'pre_4_5_jquery');
```

Comment: I've seen this solution but this is just a bandaid since my button is in a wordpress plugin I develop and maintain. https://wordpress.org/plugins/design-approval-system/